# Customize background color of Theme: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Tags: android, xml

I've used inbuilt theme `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` for my app. But it gives complete black background. I want to change this black background to gray one. So I tried to customize my theme as following:

Here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MyTheme">    // Using Customized theme.
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

//Customize the Theme.

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.8</item>
</style>
```

Here I want to lighten my background color so I'm using `android:backgroundDimAmount`  but it is not working.

I've also used following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:background">#707070</item>
</style>
```

This changes the background color, but gives me weird results as following screen shot:

[image]

Where as My actual activity looks like following screen shot:

[image]

So my question how can I lighten or possibly change the background color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want this

```
<item name="android:background">@color/<mycolor></item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/<mycolor></item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/<mycolor></item>
```

remember to change it in all styles xmls

Comment: It gives me the same screen as 1st image I've added in question.

Comment: please what is the api level you are testing on

Comment: DO NOT USE `android:background` IN THEMES! It will apply to all views without a background which is *not* what you want. `android:windowBackground` is enough.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Your suggestion worked. Please it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should use style as this in style.xml.....

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/gray</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and in colors.xml make this.....

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="gray">#707070</color><!--this your color-->
</resources>
```

[the final out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJTY8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:background` to `android:windowBackground`.
Also change the hardcoded color (e.g `#707070`) to color reference (e.g `@color/myYellowBackgroundColor`) .

When using `android:windowBackground` you tell android to affect background of child's view only inside the main activity on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your styles.xml file

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
```

remember to add your color in color.xml file. don't hardcode your color.